# US immigrant visa denial

Tags: usa, visa

Can our family-based immigrant visas, which were approved, be denied or revoked before traveling to the US? If so, what are the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Any of the grounds of inadmissibility could lead to your immigrant visa being denied or revoked.  The latter would most commonly happen at the port of entry if the examining officer discovers a ground of ineligibility during the landing interview.

Grounds of inadmissibility are codified at [8 USC 1182](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182).  There are grounds related to health, crime, and security, among others.

Regulations concerning waivers of certain grounds of inadmissibility may be found in various subparts of [8 CFR part 212](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/part-212).

As very helpfully pointed out in a [comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13750/us-immigrant-visa-denial/13752?noredirect=1#comment23411_13752) by [DJClayworth](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/556/djclayworth), this is extremely unlikely to happen for most people.  If there *are* any grounds of inadmissibility, they would most likely be discovered before the visa is issued.  The chance of new grounds arising or being discovered before arriving in the US should therefore be very low in nearly all cases.

Conversely, a person in these circumstances should be careful, because the approval of the visa does not guarantee admission.  Even after immigrating, immigrants must be careful because it is possible for a permanent resident to be [deported](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1227) under certain circumstances.

Comment: To prevent unnecessary worry you should point out that this would be very unusual.

Comment: @DJClayworth that is a most excellent point.  I will edit the answer.